# Rails to_json method: problems with unicode characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, unicode

I'm having troubles with unicode characters in my Rails app. The problem is that when I store the object with some string containing scandinavian characters, those characters then are not rendered correctly when using to_json method. Basically all those characters are rendered like this:

```
\"description\":\"\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\"
```

Here is example:

```
 Item.create(:title => "Test title", :description => "With scandic characters öäöäö")
 => #<Item id: 198, title: "Test title", priority: nil, description: "With scandic characters öäöäö", bought_when: nil, warranty_until: nil, created_at: "2012-12-04 15:22:19", updated_at: "2012-12-04 15:22:19", user_id: nil, custom_id: nil, uuid: nil, position: 1, public: nil, secure_details: "", bookmark_id: nil, giveaway: nil, trash: false>
```

At this point the created object looks ok.

```
 Item.last
```

returns

```
 => #<Item id: 198, title: "Test title", priority: nil, description: "With scandic characters \xC3\xB6\xC3\xA4\xC3\xB6\xC3\xA4\xC3\xB6", bought_when: nil, warranty_until: nil, created_at: "2012-12-04 15:22:19", updated_at: "2012-12-04 15:22:19", user_id: nil, custom_id: nil, uuid: nil, position: 1, public: nil, secure_details: "", bookmark_id: nil, giveaway: nil, trash: false>
```

This "With scandic characters \xC3\xB6\xC3\xA4\xC3\xB6\xC3\xA4\xC3\xB6" - does it still look ok? Or do I miss some proper encoding already at the item creation stage?

Anyway, now when call Item.last.to_json, I get this:

```
"description\":\"With scandic characters \\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\\ufffd\"
```

And at this point the string is definitely broken.

I'm lacking some knowledge about the proper characters encoding in Rails, so any hints would be appreciated. The item, however, looks fine when rendered in the browser - this happens only when doing a JSON response.

Comment: Are you certain that your database's character set is configured correctly?  For example, I don't think MySQL's default is UTF8, and at some point in the recent past, PostgreSQL's default was 7-bit ASCII.  It's clear that there's a transformation between the input (`Item.create`) and the output (`Item.last`) -- I would investigate that before moving on to `to_json`.

Comment: Yes, that was it! The MySQL db was not in unicode. I managed to fix this issue now by migrating to PosgreSQL using this railcast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue was that MySQL db was not in unicode. This is fixed now by migrating to PosgreSQL, ensuring it is in unicode and using Taps gem to migrate the data. All according to this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql